# Вывод исходя из времени работа со временем php

Tags: php

Ребят есть у меня такой код,

```
if( ( $tb1 == $tb2 ) ){
                $rab = "<span style=\"color: #78be20;\">Работает круглосуточно</span>";
            } elseif ( ($now + 1) >= $tb2 && $now < $tb2 ) {
                $rab = "<span style=\"color: #ec483e;\">Закроется через ". downcounter($tb2) ." </span>";
            } elseif( $currentDateTime >= $t1  && $currentDateTime < ($t2 - 1) ){
                $rab = "<span style=\"color: #78be20;\">Открыто сейчас</span>";
            } elseif ( $now >= ($tb1 - 1) && $now <= $tb1 ) {
                $rab = "<span style=\"color: #ec483e;\">Откроется через ". downcounter($tb1) ."</span>";
            } elseif ( $currentDateTime >= $t2 || $currentDateTime <= $t1) {
                $rab = "<span style=\"color: #ec483e;\">Сейчас закрыто</span>";
            }
```

Суть его работы думаю ясна, но вот у меня есть небольшая загвоздка. Если я допустим указываю режим работы с 10:00 до 04:00 то мне пишет что Сейчас закрыто. Помогите чутка доработать мой код.

Comment: что содержится в `currentDateTime`, а что в `tb1` и `tb2`? данные в одинаковом формате? Есть подозрение что нет и надо все привести к единому формату времени возможно с помощью strtotime().

Comment: Все данные у меня в едином формате

Comment: А что что где-то переменные `tb`, а местами у вас просто `t` это тоже так должно быть? Приведите полный фрагмент кода, чтобы понимать откуда какая переменная взялась.

Comment: $tb1 и $tb2 выводит время в формате 09:00 и 18:00, $t1 и $t2 преобразует время в такой формат $t1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." "09:00";

Comment: Тогда дебажте `var_dump` входящие в условие данные и переменные участвующие в сравнении чтобы разобраться куда и почему попадаете.

Comment: Так у меня все работает в моем коде, у меня вопрос был вообще в другом.Если я допустим указываю режим работы с 10:00 до 04:00 то мне пишет что Сейчас закрыто. Помогите чутка доработать мой код.

Comment: вы видимо неправильно поняли все

Comment: В любое время пишет? На каких еще промежутках работы такая ошибка? Сделайте пример который можно легко скопировать и проверить у себя, чтобы помочь. Если я сейчас возьму ваш код я не смогу сразу помочь.